# Enable default initializer list constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, initializer-list, list-initialization

I believe modern C++ initializer lists are very useful for initializing objects, to the point of removing the need for defining your own constructor:

```
struct point
{
    float coord[3];
};

point p = {1.f, 2.f, 3.f}; // nice !
```

However, this doesn't work when my class inherits from another class:

```
template<typename T>
class serializable
{
    protected:
        serializable() = default;
    ...
    // other stuff
}

struct point : public serializable<point>
{
    float coord[3];
};
point p = {1.f, 2.f, 3.f}; // Doesn't work :(
```

I tried adding `point() = default;` to my point class, but that didn't work either. How can I still initialize point with an initializer list?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your original case relied upon aggregate initialization [dcl.init.list]:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>   ...
>   — Otherwise, if `T` is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed

Where an aggregate and aggregate initialiazation are, from [dcl.init.aggr], emphasis mine:

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no private or
>   protected non-static data members (Clause 11), **no base classes (Clause 10)**, and no virtual functions (10.3).
>
> When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list, as specified in 8.5.4, the elements of the initializer list
>   are taken as initializers for the members of the aggregate, in increasing subscript or member order. Each
>   member is copy-initialized from the corresponding initializer-clause.

But now, since `point` has a base class (`serializable<point>`), `point` is no longer an aggregate and no longer supports aggregate initialization.

The solution is to simply provide such a constructor to initialize `point`:

```
struct point : public serializable<point>
{
    template <typename... T>
    point(T... ts) 
    : coord{ts...}
    { } 

    float coord[3];
};
```

Comment: Thank for you clear and detailed answer. That juste makes me wonder why the standart is as such. I'm guessing it's because constructor s wouldn't otherwise be called ... and maybe in some cases they might be conflits between the constructors and the list initialization. However as loung as all constructors are `= default` that should not cause any issue

Comment: @Amxx What if the base classes had members? What if those members were default-constructible? It's unclear what the "right thing" to do in all of these cases - so the standard chooses to not guess.

Comment: You can also stuff your data into a member or base class, like `struct point_data { float coord[3]; }`, then have a "perfect forwarding constructor" that does `{}` based construction of it.